# Redirect URL for Yammer authentication flow not working

Tags: yammer

*redirect_uri* parameter for the authentication URL for the server-side flow hasn't work when a user has to sign in to Yammer after visiting the authentication URL.

The current situation is as below:

1. A user visits
   https://www.yammer.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[:client_id]&redirect_uri=[:redirect_uri]
2. He's redirected to
   https://www.yammer.com/dialog/authenticate?client_id=[:client_id]

   - "redirect_uri" is being missed here.
3. He signs in with his Yammer account. He is redirected to his Yammer home, not redirecting back to [:redirect_uri].

Could you please investigate if it's an issue to be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

use the below code.

```
https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[clientid]&response_type=code&redirect_uri=[redirect url]?error=[:error]&error_description=[:error_description]
```

Replace your client id and redirect url only in the above line. Rest keep the same.

Also, Please make sure the redirect url you have mentioned while registering the app key matches with the redirect_uri above.

[image]